# Uploading 2GB file to Sharepoint Document Library using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

Hi guys I have a scenario where I have to upload a file of size 2GB to SharePoint document library using c# and asp.net file upload control. I have tried this but I faced an issue because the maximum upload size of upload control is 4MB. So I increased the maxRequestLength  to 2Gb and RequestTimeout also. but it is taking more than 30 mins to upload the file. I have used the filestream method to do this. Can anybody give me a idea to upload the file in chunks to make the process more faster?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define that on Central Administration, [as explained here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424404%28office.14%29.aspx#Section3c)

> In order to configure the upload file size in SharePoint Server 2010, a farm administrator must change the Maximum Upload Size value on the Web Application General Settings page in Central Administration.

For upload in chunks, you'll need to deploy a handler to deal with your chunks requests and manipulate SharePoint objects, like SPFile. However, every call for a document through this method returns the whole document so far stored on SharePoint.

If that is a typical file size, you should consider to store the partial file on filesystem and, when you finish it, transfer all it into SharePoint.